# Cannot read length property of undefined

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to render the length of the    state to the screen and it keeps telling me, cannot read length property of undefined. When i tried logging the value of state to the console, at first it was undefined, after running a search the value updated and  there were 5 items in the array. problem now is when it updates, it does not update on the screen, either that or it flat out crashes.

```
export default class App extends Component {
    state={
       vidoes:[]
   };

    onTermSubmit = async term =>{
   const response = await youtube.get('/search',{
        params:{
            q:term,
        }
    });

    this.setState({videos:response.data.items})
   };



    render() {
        console.log(this.state.videos)
        return (
            <div className="ui container">
                <SearchBar onFormSubmit={this.onTermSubmit}/>
                {this.state.vidoes.length}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

The ultimate goal is to have the length of state render on the screen and now that it is being described as undefined, it will be impossible to loop throght it.

Comment: Well, first of all I assume that in the third line instead of "Vidoes" you meant "Videos", so correcting it is a good starting to get through the problem :)

Comment: what if you wrap it in a `if` statement  `if(response && response.data) { this.setState({videos:response.data.items}) }`

Comment: hello, i have work with react once time and i think when you call set state, state is not refresh immediatly, its asynchronous. you have to add a callback in you setstate method and callback will be called when update done, or you can use componentDidUpdate() function. its just for help perhaps render method is always called when state is update...

Comment: @NéstorCarreñoGimeno turns out that was the problem lol i can't believe i spent 5 hours just to find out its a stupid typo

Comment: @swapnesh oh yeah, i definitely will implement that now! forgot that bit

Comment: @tyjaniihassan you are welcome! It happens to all of us at least once haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```
  export default class App extends Component {
            state={
               videos:[]
           };

            onTermSubmit = async term =>{
           const response = await youtube.get('/search',{
                params:{
                    q:term,
                }
            });

            this.setState({videos:response.data.items})
           };



            render() {
                console.log(this.state.videos)
                return (
                    <div className="ui container">
                        <SearchBar onFormSubmit={this.onTermSubmit}/>
                        {this.state.videos.length}
                    </div>
                )
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some typo `videos`. Please change it to `this.state.videos.length` in **render** method.

```
render() {
        console.log(this.state.videos)
        return (
            <div className="ui container">
                <SearchBar onFormSubmit={this.onTermSubmit}/>
                {this.state.videos.length}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Hope this will work for you.